# Using Terminal in Recovery Mode - Multiple Volumes on Disk

Tags: recovery, disk-volume

I have two versions of MacOS on my computer in different volumes.  If I open a Terminal window in Recovery Mode, which volume will I be looking at?  I'm specifically looking at files in /System/Library/.  Are these files shared between the two volumes, or is there a way to switch which volume I'm looking at?

Thanks.
-Brett

Comment: You're probably looking at the filesystem in the recovery partition.

Comment: Ah! I hadn't thought of that, but it makes sense since I'm in Recovery Mode.  Thanks.  Still wondering if there's a way to switch volumes.  I'm not a *nix expert so could be missing something obvious.

Comment: Look into `/Volumes`. If the other partitions are not there, you can mount them.